# Reason to convert datatable to List of<>

Tags: datatable, vb.net-2010

I see a lot of people asking the question of how to convert a data table to `List Of<>`. I am trying to understand what are the reasons to convert from data table to  `List Of<>` or when would be it be better to use the `List Of<>` instead of data table.

As I see it if I am retriving data from the database and can assign the data source to a grid, listbox etc why would I want to convert it to `List Of<>` and what would be an advantage of converting it to a `List Of<>` ?

Comment: Type safety is wonderful...

Comment: While there are Typed DataSets, they require extra setup (which has ups and downs). So I generally use IEnumerable<T> for *non-dynamic* data (read dynamically, perhaps) and DataTable for *dynamic* data .. whichever is easier/cleaner for the task.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner to understand your comments. Can you provide an example of what you mean.